# Equation Parser for Graphing in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: parsing, graph-algorithm, graphing

**I want an Equation Parser so that it can solve for x as well as for y to get an array of points (i.e. x and y).**

Example:

*Let us assume a user enter the expression:*

```
var expression ="x + y = 1";
```

*Now let us say I know the domain and ranges:*

```
var xMin = -10, yMin = -10, xMax = 10 ,yMax = 10;
```

**So what I want is the plotting points between these ranges and domain.**

**Means I want an array or two dimensional array holding the value of x coordinates and y coordinates.**

Please can anybody suggest me how to get up to here using any algorithm or a program.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this parser
http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/

Comment: Thanks , I tried this already but I am not getting the desired result i want from this

Comment: How did you try to use it?Do you have a sample code?I guess if you can parse equation using this library then you can evaluate the equation for the given range of values and create array of result coordinates.

Comment: Thanks a ton! , I went through this again it might help me in getting the desired output , Trying a new logic , can u prepare a fiddle if possible for you taking the string/expression above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After parsing the equation to standard form, you could substitute different values depending on number of points required from the given range for one unknown variable i.e. for this example, say x and get corresponding y values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. "parser.js" can be downloaded from here 
https://github.com/silentmatt/js-expression-eval/tree/master

Take a look at this as well,might be helpful 
http://silentmatt.com/javascript-function-plotter/

```
     <html>
<head>
<script src="parser.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<script>


$( document ).ready(function() {
var xMin = -10, yMin = -10, xMax = 10 ,yMax = 10;
var rangeIncrement=1;

var equation="";
var points=[];

$( "#btnDraw" ).click(function() {
points=[];
equation=$("#txtequation").val()
expr = Parser.parse(equation);
i=0;
for(i=xMin  ;i<=xMax ;i+=rangeIncrement)
{
  result=expr.evaluate({ x: i});
    points.push([i, result]);
}
$( "#resultPoints" ).empty();
$.each(points, function( index, value ) {
  $( "#resultPoints" ).append( "<p>X="+value[0] +", Y="+ value[1]+"</p>" );
});

});
});



</script>
</head>
<body>
var xMin = -10, yMin = -10, xMax = 10 ,yMax = 10;
<br>
var rangeIncrement=1;
<br>
Y= <input type="text" id="txtequation"  value="x+1" /><button id="btnDraw">Draw</button>
<br>
<div id="resultPoints"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks useful Thanks!!

Comment: This is useful for equation in terms of something : what if the equation is of the form x+y=1 ,?

Comment: I tried to find a parser lib that would parse "x+y=1",unfortunately i couldn't find one.If you encounter one you can simply replace the parser library i have used here.

Comment: Anyway take  look at this http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2011/08/math-evaluator-in-javascript-part1.html
this lib can convert strin function to token.using this you might be able to write your own parser.

Comment: Ok Thanks , will check it

Comment: http://www.mathpapa.com/calc.html?q=y%3Dx%5E2+1 try contacting these guys.I checked they are doing equation solving it in client side most probably using javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85198/discussion-between-vishal-kumar-mitra-and-deshanr).